# without damaging metal, how to attach metal house numbers to metal sheathing

Tags: installation

I am hoping to find a way to attach my metal house numbers to facia clad with metal sheathing without damaging the metal. the

Answer (score 1):

Automotive trim tape.

For example, 3M 38583 (I'm not in any way associated with 3M, but I did just buy a roll of the stuff for the automotive purpose it's intended for.)

Weatherproof, lasts a long time, and if you need to remove them you saw them off with a section of fishing line and then rub the remaining adhesive off (they even make a special tool for THAT job for the automotive application, but I haven't bought one as I doubt the scale of my job calls for it.)

Answer (score 0):

If the metal is steel, then magnetic vinyl/rubber sheet